# How to optimize the running time for array_aggreration XML

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql, aggregate-functions

I use For XML Path('') function to get the columns: report_name aggregated, but I found it takes too long to run the query. Does anyone know how to optimize this? The CTE part only takes 15 seconds while the total query time takes more than 10 mins.

Table: **emsp_order_raw_data**

| column | datatype |
| --- | --- |
| category | VARCHAR(20) |
| report_name | VARCHAR(50) |
| order_id | VARCHAR(30) |
| amount | FLOAT |

**Sample data**

| category | report_name | order_id | amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ORDER LEVEL | All the report jan2020 | 20201212 | 500 |
| - ORDER LEVEL | Second report jan2020 | 20201213 | 400 |
| ORDER LEVEL | Third report jan2020 | 20201214 | 300 |
| - ORDER LEVEL | Credit jan2020 | 20201212 | 300 |

**The result**

| order_id | period_month | amountd | report_name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 20201212 | 2020-01 | 200 | All the report,Credit |
| 20201213 | 2020-01 | 400 | Second report |
| 20201214 | 2020-01 | 300 | Third report |

```
-- change the amount from the '- order level' to be negative
With amount_change(category, report_name, order_id, amount) AS (
    SELECT category, 
           report_name, 
           order_id, 
           CASE WHEN category ='- ORDER LEVEL' THEN amount* -1
                ELSE amount
                END AS amount 
    FROM emsp_order_raw_data    
),
-- separate the report month from report_name
group_updated_order_raw_data(report_name, period_month, order_id, amount) AS (
    SELECT 
           CASE WHEN LEFT(report_name, len(report_name)-7) IS NULL THEN 'No Report Name' ELSE LEFT(report_name, len(report_name)-7) END AS report_name,
           SUBSTRING(CAST(CONVERT(DATE,'01' + LEFT(RIGHT(report_name,7),3) + RIGHT(report_name,4),106) AS VARCHAR(10)),1,7) AS period_month,
           CASE WHEN order_id is null THEN 'No Order ID' ELSE order_id END AS order_id, 
           SUM(amount) AS amount
    FROM amount_change
    GROUP BY order_id, report_name
)
-- Group report_name, amount by order
SELECT C.order_id,
       C.period_month,
       SUM(C.amount) as amount,
       (SELECT report_name + ',' 
        FROM group_updated_order_raw_data 
        WHERE group_updated_order_raw_data.order_id = C.order_id
        FOR XML PATH('')) as report_name
FROM group_updated_order_raw_data C
GROUP BY order_id, period_month
```

Comment: @Tomalak I edited the question and added the table schemas and sample data.

Comment: SQL Server 2017+ supports `string_agg`

Comment: @Serg Thanks, it is workable now.

Comment: Side note: `DATEFROMPARTS` can be useful in getting the first day in the month